# Unrecognized command line option ‘-mwindows’

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile my hello world app on C from Ubuntu linux for Windows platform. So, to compile the app I am using this Makefile:

```
CC = g++
IDIR = -Iinclude
SRC = src
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra
LFLAGS = -mwindows

main.out: main.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IDIR) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

main.o: $(SRC)/main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IDIR) -c -o $@ $^
```

As the result of cmmand `make -f windows.mk` I have such error:

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mwindows’
```

I have already tried gcc and g++. Is there way to compile it without making my own crosscompiler?

Comment: A build of GCC can compile for one platform only. You can't reuse your regular GCC to cross-compile for Windows. A different GCC needs to be installed separately. (`sudo apt install mingw-w64` I think).  `-mwindows` just means "don't show the terminal window when running my program", it doesn't assist in cross-compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cross compile for windows you would need mingw-w64 or use i686-w64-mingw32-g++
`sudo apt-get install mingw-w64` 
For more info :
https://arrayfire.com/cross-compile-to-windows-from-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot @HolyBlackCat
I've tried to using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` instead of just `g++` or `gcc` without  `-mwindows` and it succeed.